# Wordpress api route to create user return "invalid username"

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create new user through the WordPress API with some request like:

```
POST https://sandbox.***.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: "basic auth using application password generated on wordpress"

Body (JSON):
{
  "username": "Imatest",
  "email": "gsdyee@azerty.ch",
  "password": "1234"
}
```

But the server returns me :

```
{
    "code": "invalid_username",
    "message": "<strong>Error :</strong> unknown identifier. Check again or try with your email address.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I don't see any specification required for the username in the doc so I'm confused, futhermore, the id is obviously unknown since it's a new user.
Any Idea what's going on?